# Shallow copy: is the Python.org documentation wrong?

Tags: python

Is the official documentation on Python.org wrong, or did I interpret something wrongly?

Near the end of the [Lists Section](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) of the documentation in "An Informal Introduction to Python", one can find the following description about copying lists:

> Simple assignment in Python never copies data. When you assign a list to a variable, the variable refers to the existing list. Any changes you make to the list through one variable will be seen through all other variables that refer to it.:
>
> ```py
> >>> rgb = ["Red", "Green", "Blue"]
> >>> rgba = rgb
> >>> id(rgb) == id(rgba)  # they reference the same object True
> >>> rgba.append("Alph")
> >>> rgb ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Alph"]
> ```

So I understand that the new list is a reference to the original list. But immediately then, the documentation states:

> All slice operations return a new list containing the requested elements. This means that the following slice returns a [shallow copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#shallow-vs-deep-copy) of the list:
>
> ```py
> >>> correct_rgba = rgba[:]
> >>> correct_rgba[-1] = "Alpha"
>
> >>> correct_rgba ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Alpha"]
>
> >>> rgba ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Alph"]
> ```

So, if I understand correctly:

- `rgba[:]` is the slice operation
- this makes a *shallow copy* of the original list
- it copies data from the original, into a new list that isn't a reference to the original

But:

- after reading about the [difference between *shallow* and *deep* copies](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#shallow-vs-deep-copy), I understand that *shallow copies* are references to their original, whilst *deep copies* are independent (unreferenced) copies
- in the example above, the documentation creates a *deep copy* but mentions it as a *shallow copy*?

Comment: Shallow copies _contain_ references to the same values as the original did - what the documentation calls a shallow copy _is a shallow copy_.  If shallow copies were references to the original, i.e. `a = b[:]` and `a = b` were indistinguishable, they wouldn't be copies at all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe But the documentation itself states that changes in *shallow copies* reflect to their originals, whereas in the example code that doesn't happen; I've tried it on my Python interpreter (iPython) and it didn't reflect either. Isn't that what a *deep copy* does?

Comment: No, it states _simple assignment_ reflects changes in the originals, shallow copies are _explicitly_ shown to be different. For shallow vs. deep copying, you need to think about mutable collections _of mutable collections_ (of...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing two concepts that are important in Python. On the one hand there's *shallow copy* vs *deep copy*, and on the other there's *assignment by object reference*.

When you assign a value to a variable in Python, the value is stored in memory and a reference to that location is stored in the variable. This is true for any value, because everything in Python is an object. There are some optimisations, like Python pre-allocating small integers, but the principle is always the same.

```
a = 1234  # 1234 is stored in memory somewhere, `a` is assigned a reference
```

When defining a list, things are a bit more complicated, but essentially the same. For example, for this:

```
xs = [1001, 1002, 1003]
```

A list object is created, and a reference to it is stored in `xs`. However, the list itself contains references to the numbers which in turn are stored somewhere in memory.

When you assign one variable to another, the reference is copied. So, when running this after the previous two examples:

```
b, ys = a, xs
print(id(a), id(b), id(xs), id(ys))
```

You can tell that `a` and `b` point to the exact same value in memory, as do `xs` and `ys`. This is assignment by object reference in action.

This means that if a variable refers to a mutable value, all variables referring to the same value will continue to point to the same mutable value, regardless of changes. So:

```
ys[0] = 1004
print(xs)  # prints [1004, 1002, 1003]
```

This same behaviour does not happen with *immutable* types, because Python will create a new value when you apply an operation to that, and won't automatically update any variables referring to the value being changed. For example:

```
s = 'hello'
t = s
s += ' world'
print(t)  # `t` continues to refer to `'hello'`, `s` now refers to a `'hello world'`
```

A completely new `'hello world'` value results, and `s` refers to that value in memory.

If you don't want the behaviour on mutable objects, that `xs` and `ys` show, you can create a copy instead:

```
xs = [1001, 1002, 1003]
ys = xs[:]  # creating a copy (a shallow one, more soon)
xs[0] = 1004
print(xs[0], ys[0])  # prints `1004 1001`
```

Not that `xs[:]` is convenient shorthand for create a shallow copy of a list with a slice. However, more generically, for a shallow copy you could:

```
from copy import copy

xs = [1001, 1002, 1003]
ys = copy(xs)  # creating a shallow copy
xs[0] = 1004
print(xs[0], ys[0])  # prints `1004 1001`
```

But what if `xs` was a list of lists? If a copy is created of that list, what is in the copy?

```
xs = [[1001, 1002], [1003, 1004]]
ys = xs[:]  # creating a shallow copy
xs[0][0] = 1005
print(xs[0], ys[0])  # prints `[1005, 1002] [1005, 1002]`
```

Hopefully unsurprisingly, because `ys` is just a shallow copy of `xs`, it contains references to the same lists that are in `xs`. So, changing one of those lists, will be reflected when accessing it through `ys` as well.

If you don't want that, but you want `ys` to contain a fully new copy recursively, you can make a *deep copy*:

```
from copy import deepcopy

xs = [[1001, 1002], [1003, 1004]]
ys = deepcopy(xs)  # creating a deep copy
xs[0][0] = 1005
print(xs[0], ys[0])  # prints `[1005, 1002] [1001, 1002]`
```

Now, `ys` does not just contain a copy of the references in `xs`, but for all those references (recursively) new copies have been made and `ys` has the exact same structure and content, but they are all separate copies.

This gets a bit hairy when the contents of `xs` are not just basic types, but types that don't implement `__deepcopy__`. But that's another question.

Comment: I wish all the examples online would differentiate between "referencing vs shallow copy vs deep copy", not only the later two. I also come from a JS background but never new the concept of shallow copies. This answer has clarified the topic better for me, addressing my confusion.

Comment: You're welcome - I made a last edit adding in a reference to `copy()` which is the more generic way to create a shallow copy (whereas slicing is specific to objects that support slicing), from the same module as `deepcopy()`.

Answer (score 2):

Shallow copies make a new list with *same* elements.

Deep copies make a new list, but recursively make new *mutable* elements.

Examples.  Note that `is` compares object *identity* (same object), not equality (same value):

```
>>> L=[[1]]               # A list of lists

>>> M=L                   # assignment
>>> M is L, M[0] is L[0]  # M is same list, and same elements
(True, True)
>>> L.append(2)           # add to the list and M changes
>>> M
[[2], 2]
>>> L[0][0]=2             # change sub-element and M changes
>>> M
[[2]]

>>> M=L[:]                # shallow copy
>>> M is L, M[0] is L[0]  # M is new list with same elements
(False, True)
>>> L.append(3)           # Add to list and M does not change
>>> M
[[2], 2]
>>> L[0][0]=3             # Change sub-element and M changes
>>> M
[[3], 2]

>>> import copy
>>> M=copy.deepcopy(L)    # Deep copy
>>> M is L, M[0] is L[0]  # New list and new mutable sub-element
(False, False)
>>> L.append(4)           # Add to list and M does not change
>>> M
[[3], 2, 3]
>>> L[0][0]=4             # Change sub-element and M does not change
>>> M
[[3], 2, 3]
```

Comment: I think I get it now. Does the references only work with +2D lists?

Comment: @GuiImamura Deep copies make new items of anything mutable in a list.  You could have a 1D list of mutable class instances for example.

Comment: Maybe I should have explained I come from a Javascript background. In JS, if `a = [0, 1]` and `b = a`, then `a[0] = 1` reflects to `b // returns [1,1] now` (you can try it on your browser's console, hit `F12`). According to [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/copying-stuff-in-javascript-how-to-differentiate-between-deep-and-shallow-copies-b6d8c1ef09cd/), this is a shallow copy in JS.

Comment: My mistake. TIL to make a shallow copy in JS you have to use the notation `b = [...a]`. I didn't know about shallow copies, only references to the full object and deep copies. Thanks for the clarification.